# Ошибка: argument of type 'function' is not iterable при добавление системы для регистрации пользователя

Tags: python, django

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp1.views import index, about, work, regist
from myapp1.views import register

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('prices/', about),
    path('drinks/', work),
    path('regist/',  register, name=regist),
]
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # Дополнительные поля, если нужно
    pass
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')
def work(request):
    return render(request, 'work.html')
def regist(request):
    return render(request, 'regist.html')

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from myapp1.forms import CustomUserCreationForm
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration_form.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from myapp1.models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

**regist.html:**

```html
<!-- registration_form.html -->
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </form>
```

**Полная ошибка:**

> Watching for file changes with StatReloader Performing system
> checks...
>
> Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py",
> line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py",
> line 946, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
> line 64, in wrapper
> fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
> line 133, in inner_run
> self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 485, in check
> all_issues = checks.run_checks(   File "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",
> line 88, in run_checks
> new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)   File
> "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> line 14, in check_url_config
> return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> line 24, in check_resolver
> return check_method()   File "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 517, in check
> messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))   File "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> line 24, in check_resolver
> return check_method()   File "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 408, in check
> warnings = self._check_pattern_name()   File "C:\Users\Ризамат\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 417, in _check_pattern_name
> if self.pattern.name is not None and ":" in self.pattern.name: TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable